# What is the meaning of "muffed" in "muffed music"?

Tags: word-meaning

What is the meaning of word "muffed " in sentence "muffed pop music" ?

Comment: Are you absolutely, positively certain that someone did not mispell "muffled"?

Comment: "To muff" means 'to handle clumsily or badly'. I would say, "muffed pop music" means 'pop music that is performed badly'.

Comment: I'm not certain that it was spelled correctly..

Comment: First, "muffed pop music" is not a sentence. And more importantly,  you shouldn't ask a question here until you're certain about what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of the phrase "muffed music" having a recognized meaning. If it's a technical term in the music industry or a slang term in some segment of the population that doesn't include me, others feel free to chime in here. You might give a reference to where you read this.

I suspect this is a typo for "muffled music". To "muffle" a sound is to cover it up so that it is difficult to hear, accidentally or deliberately. Like you might say, "We installed acoustic tiles to muffle the sound of the machinery", or, "The kidnapper put his hand over her mouth to muffle her screams." A car "muffler" is a device to reduce the noise made by the exhaust.

Another possibility: "Muff" is an old slang term meaning to make a mistake or to fail. Like, "I muffed the entropy question on the physics test." Or simply, "Wow, you really muffed up bad that time, George." I haven't hear this in a while but depending on your source, it's possible. In that case "muffed music" could mean "I tried to play this piece of music but I got several notes wrong", etc.